# Xcode crashes while trying to create relationship between tabbarcontroller and Navigation view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

Im trying to create a relationship between a navigation view controller and a tab bar controller to create a new tab but when Im doing so, the app crashes. How can I solve it? Following is the screenshot of how im creating it.

[image]

Error log

> Application Specific Information: Sending connectionWellDragged: to
>    from  ProductBuildVersion: 7C1002 UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
>   (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x7fff71d5b6d0 UserInfo: (null) Hints:    0: Sending
>   connectionWellDragged: to 
>   from

Comment: post your error what you getting

Comment: I have posted the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not give relationship to navigation controller like this. select your tabViewcontroller (you tab not tabBarController) and from editor `embed in navigationController`. so, it will automatically embed navigation controller between tab and tabbarcontroller. hope this will help :)

Comment: I selected tabbar controller scene then I selected embed in option from editor option followed by embed in option but Im unable to select  navigation controller icon since its disabled

Comment: select tabViewcontroller (means your first tab or second tab viewController etc). you can't embed in navigation controller to tabbarcontroller

Comment: If you want to embed navigation controller to tabbarcontroller then ctrl + drag from navigation controller to tabbarcontroller and from popup select `root View controller` under `relationship segue`

Comment: i selected tabViewcontroller and over there there is an option available to embed in tab bar controller but not navigation controller

Comment: now i have connected both but the tabview controller is showing only one tab not the new tab that I have connected

Comment: if you want to add anothet tab then drag new view controller and ctrl + drag from tab bar controller to that viewController and from popup select  `root View controller` under `relationship segue` as you do just before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110342/discussion-between-user22312412-and-lion).

Comment: i wish I could up vote this answer multiple times. This saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do following.

- Right click on navigation bar and drag to tab bar controller.
- Release right click when you are on tab bar controller.
- A menu appears, from that menu select `rootViewController` and now both are connected.

[image]